# How can I make it so that the text in this Text widget refreshes every second?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to make a clock app and hence require the time to be displayed on the home screen, but the time only shows when the screen is initialized and then does not change after the screen has been initialised, I have tried using set state but it's not working.

```
class ClockInfo extends StatefulWidget {
  const ClockInfo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ClockInfoState createState() => _ClockInfoState();
}

class _ClockInfoState extends State<ClockInfo> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer){
      setState(() {
        nowMinute = now.minute.toString().padLeft(2, "0");
        nowHour = now.hour.toString().padLeft(2, "0");
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 110, 0, 20),
          child: Text(
            nowHour + ":" + nowMinute,
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 60,
                color:  Colors.white
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

The following variables are defined globally

```
var now = DateTime.now();
var nowMinute;
var nowHour;
var nowDate = now.day.toString();
var nowDay = now.weekday;
var nowMonth = now.month;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working because `now` is not updated on every tick.

```dart
class _ClockInfoState extends State<ClockInfo> {
  String nowMinute = '', nowHour = '', nowSeconds = '';
  @override
  void initState() {
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        nowMinute = DateTime.now().minute.toString().padLeft(2, "0");
        nowHour = DateTime.now().hour.toString().padLeft(2, "0");
        nowSeconds = DateTime.now().second.toString().padLeft(2, "0");
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      Text('Time now'),
      Text(
        nowHour + ":" + nowMinute + ":" + nowSeconds,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60, color: Colors.black),
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```